# How can I create a new space type in blender using python?

Tags: python, interface

is there a way to create a custom bl space type in blender with a new header. also, Height of header is predefined, is there a way to increase the height of header and tool header?

Comment: No, you can't create a new `bl_space_type` but you can modify the existing header or tool header height.

Comment: How can I adjust the height of header or tool header?

Comment: Sorry, you can't change height of header and tool header